# Oracle DB-Link call remote function not working

Tags: oracle

In Oracle, I have a database link to another Oracle database. I want to call a function on the other database (remote execute functions). Just testing with simple "substr".

Why is this not working?

```
select stringCol, substr@remoteDb(stringCol,1,2)
from thatTable@remoteDb
```

Do I need special permissions?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot reference built-in *SQL* functions (like `SUBSTR`) over a dblink using the @ syntax. It should execute remotely without the `@dblink` syntax, being passed through to the remote as part of the SQL. Oracle knows that `SUBSTR` is the same everywhere.

You only call functions with `@dblink` to specify where they are when they are *PL/SQL functions* (whether yours or built-in), which are not guaranteed to be the same in one database as another. So, you should test it with an actual compiled PL/SQL function, packaged or standalone, custom or built-in.

Comment: Assume substr is different on the other db but is built in - just a fictional example. Would it then be possible to call it with @dblink?

Comment: @Lopo, it's not possible: `SUBSTR` is built-in to the Oracle SQL engine and is compiled code in C, not PL/SQL. It cannot be different. `dbms_lob.substr`, on the other hand, is PL/SQL and *could* be different if someone (wrongly) were to replace it with a custom version. Either way, the latter can be called with `@dblink` like any PL/SQL program can. Built-in SQL functions  like `SUBSTR` cannot.